# Custom ImageView getting resized automatically on Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a custom ImageView that covers the whole screen. The image is sourced from one of the drawable folders, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-sw600dp etc. and there are separate images for each density bucket.

So far, the application works fine on xhdpi and hdpi devices, the problem occurs when I test it on a Nexus 7. The image stored in the sw600dp folder has a size of 1600x1600 and should be enough to directly draw on the screen (without scaling), however when I run the app, the screen turns out to be completely blank and I get the following warning:

> 03-04 16:25:46.338: W/OpenGLRenderer(25457): Bitmap too large to be
>   uploaded into a texture (2130x2130, max=2048x2048)

For some reason the 1600x1600 bitmap is scaled to 2130x2130 although I have not manually scaled it anywhere (no matrix postscale or scaleX/scaleY applied)

Any thoughts on why this might be happening? Please provide a solution along with the explanation of why this might be happening.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Nexus 7 is tvdpi, it scales every image to 1.33 of the original value. So 1600 becomes (1600*1.33)= ~2130. It wont display it from the sw600dp folder.

More Info:-http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You can use the same image which you are using for every other 7 inch tablet ( i.e. of resolution 1024*600 ).

Comment: Thanks Kunal, that was an awesome answer, I indeed put the image in the drawable-tvdpi directory and it worked fine. Thanks a lot. Lesson: drawable-sw600dp images are scaled when being displayed on a nexus 7 while a drawable-tvdpi will not.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share some info about error you are getting..

**According to [Romain Guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/I1LHdmUbb5k)** **(Android framework engineer)**:

> ***When using hardware acceleration, there is a limit to the size of a
>   texture. When you render a bitmap, it has to be uploaded to an OpenGL
>   texture first. Your bitmap happens to be bigger than the maximum
>   texture size on Xoom (2048x2048.) You need to use a smaller bitmap or
>   split it into several bitmaps.***

Other SO Links may be helpful to you : **[click here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108841/how-to-catch-error-bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture)**, [**click here2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180382/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture)

Git: **[click here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/98)**

Update: This  answer only tells why error is happening (becauseof texture size limit) sorry it's not a full answer for why 1600x1600 bitmap is scaled to 2130x2130!!

Comment: I was aware of the limit, the question was why the 1600x1600 image is getting scaled to something above 2048x2048